# C++ Namespace inferred

Tags: c++

Been a long time since I used C++ and came across something in some code I was reading today:

Why doesn't `exists` below need qualifying with `std::filesystem::`. I've not been able to work out how that prefix is inferred (partly as I don't even know what to search for).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path input_path("c:\\temp\\foo.txt");
    std::error_code fs_error;
    if (!exists(input_path, fs_error))
    {
        std::cout << "Error: folder or file " << input_path << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There we go - it's called Argument Dependent lookup.

Comment: Yeah, not something you'll be able to find without help